# Is it possible to save a class using django redis cache to use it after the user reconnects

Tags: python, django, class, caching, websocket

I need to save a class to use it if the websocket disconnects and assign it to the websocket again if it reconnects.

But when saving i get this error: "Exception inside application: Can't pickle local object" which i think is because i cant save a class to the cache. Is it possible to overcome this and save the class in the cache?